# ¿Cómo obtener el 'href' de un enlace sin recargar la página?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax

Saludos a toda la comunidad.
quisiera saber si me pueden ayudar a obtener la URL de un enlace que esta en una pagina `.php`, para poder "extraer" las variables GET que este tiene por medio de JavaScript, para luego hacer una petición AJAX con dichas variables. 
Pero el problema es que necesito que no se recargue la pagina para poder hacerlo. Por ejemplo tengo la pagina `ejemplo.php`:

```
<a href="index.php?id=<?php echo $producto['id']; echo'&p='.pagina_actual();?>" 
   class="abrir-vista-producto">
   <p><?php echo $producto['nombre']?></p>
</a>
```

y el `.js` donde quiero obtener la URL:

```
$("a.abrir-vista-producto").click(function(e) {
    var variables_get = window.location.search;
    alert(variables_get);
    e.preventDefault();
  });
```

pero al ejecutar este código la URL no cambia por el `e.preventDefault()` y si comento dicha linea, por obvias razones la URL si cambia pero me recarga la página.

La verdad es que voy empezando en esto, por ende mi alcance para dar solución a este problema es muy limitado, así que cualquier ayuda me serviría de mucho, gracias.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Si te entendi bien, lo que quieres es sacar los parametros de el URL de el link y mandarlos por ajax.  Puedes obtener el atributo `href` con jQuery y despues parsearlo.  Algo asi:

```js
$("a.abrir-vista-producto").click(function(e) {
    var variables_get = $(this).attr('href');
    var vars = [], hash;
    var hashes = variables_get.slice(variables_get.indexOf('?') + 1).split('&');
    
    for(var i = 0; i < hashes.length; i++)
    {
        hash = hashes[i].split('=');
        vars.push(hash[0]);
        vars[hash[0]] = hash[1];
    }    
    console.log(vars.p);
    console.log(vars.id);
    // Aqui puedes hacer tu peticion Ajax con los valores obtenidos
    e.preventDefault();
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="index.php?id=1&p=p1" class="abrir-vista-producto"><p>producto</p></a>
```

Comment: perfecto, me funciono a la perfección, muchas gracias.

Answer (score 2):

Intenta :

```
$('.hrefClass > img').live("click", function()
{          
    alert($(this).parent().attr("href"));  

    return false;    
});
```

> La part**e $ (this)** apunta a la imagen en la que el usuario hizo clic, la función parent () encuentra el elemento primario inmediato de la imagen en la que se hace clic, y la función **attr** () obtiene el valor del atributo href de ese elemento primario.
>
> Finalmente, la declaración falsa de devolución asegura que la acción
>   predeterminada del enlace, que está abriendo otra url, no ocurre. Si
>   desea permitir la acción predeterminada, omita esta declaración de
>   devolución.

Autor de la respuesta: [MD Sayem Ahmed](https://stackoverflow.com/users/245679/md-sayem-ahmed)

pregunta original:

[get href value with loaded page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6569645/get-href-value-with-loaded-page)